# Looping through multiple ranges

Tags: vba, loops, excel, range

Okay so I'm trying to do a "for each" loop that loops through multiple ranges. To explain it better I want excel to loop through a column of contract names and where each contract that has been signed this month (indicated by a "S" in the column to the right of the contract column) i want to check if it is also indicated as signed the month before.

The month before is a different workbook but I assume that I can just make that table a named range a refer to that in my formula. At this point we arrive at my problem.  In my for each loop I have "for each cell in range(X)" but that refers to the first workbook (this month instead of last month) so I don't know how to reference the second workbook in my "if statement" (if wbkA range("A").offset(0, 1).value = to "S" and wbkB range("A").offset(0, 1) = "S")

There is a third part to what I want to do but I'm pretty sure if I can figure it out if someone can help me with this part.

Please let me know if my question is ambiguous and I'll try to elaborate. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you show the code you have at the moment this will enable us to assist you more.

Comment: At this point, I think we can also raise the question as to why you are keeping your data in separate workbooks each month instead of pushing it into a DB.

Comment: I think a `lookup` is best for this. A loop seems overkill.

Comment: Sean - glh is right that you code achieve what you want with simple `vlookup` formulas. Is each `contract name` a unique name?

Comment: completely agree. vlookup! no need for code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access different workbooks from `Application.Workbooks(index or name)` or `Application.Workbooks.Open(...)` if it's closed.

So:

```
Dim wbkA as Workbook 
Dim wbkB as Workbook

'If both are open being A the first and B the second:
Set wbkA = Application.Workbooks(1)
Set wbkB = Application.Workbooks(2)
```

You can also check their names to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use item() for one of the two workbooks:

```
Set objBook1 = Workbooks("April.xls")
Set objSheet1 = objBook1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rangeInBook1 = objSheet1.Range("A1:A5")

Set objBook2 = Workbooks("May.xls")
Set objSheet2 = objBook2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rangeInBook2 = objSheet2.Range("A1:A5")

book2Index = 1
For Each objRng In rangeInBook1
    itemFromBook1 = objRng.Value
    itemFromBook2 = rangeInBook2.Item(book2Index)
    book2Index = book2Index + 1
Next
```

Comment: @Alex P yes each contract name Is a unique name. Any ideas cause I'm still having the same issue? Also it has to be VBA because its part of a much larger macro